# On the Bhattacharyya distance

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variables with support $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and with PDF $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. If the [Bhattacharyya distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance) of $f$ and $g$ is less than $\epsilon$, then is there any (lower or upper) bound on $\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(1+x)(f(x)-g(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: No. The Bhattacharyya distance is invariant under shifting both distributions to larger $x$, but your integral increases in magnitude unboundedly under such a transformation.